Codebeamer Excel Import failed
In my current project we are using the tool Codebeamer to track our requirements and testcases. For batch updates on the testcases I exported a roundtrip Excel and changed the Status field to Draft for the items I wanted to change.
I then started the straightforward import process and the last page of the import dialogue also showed no problem. It just showed by yellow background that only the Status attribute of my desired items will be changed to draft.
I started the import, but at some point the import was aborted being only partially carried out. Instead I am getting an error message box, but no indication what causes this error.
Does anyone knows how to further investigate on the reason of this error?

